# installing a signal handler for a process? Can it be clarified that it cannot be uninstalled?

Tags: operating-system

I dont see any other sources on stack overflow, but is it true when you install a signal handler for a process, it therefore cannot be uninstalled? If this is true can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct.  You can uninstall a signal handler perfectly well, by calling `signal` or `sigaction` again to either replace your handler with a different signal handler, or change the action to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`.